# Sequelize Pool related Issue

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, connection-pooling

When the webapp developed using SEAN stack(Sequelize, Express, Angular, Nodejs) becomes idle and the user is logged out after timeout, sequelize/tedious is throwing below exception.

Any pointers on sequelize connection pooling or standard way of db connection release would be helpful.

Error is "**Resource not currently part of this pool**"

Versions used:

Tedious version **2.0.0**

Sequelize version **4.1.0**

Error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Resource not currently part of this pool
    at Pool.destroy (\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\generic-pool\lib\Pool.js:450:35)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\connection-manager.js:124:25)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Connection.socketError (\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:703:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1257:8)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same error but it does not cause my app crashing. So I have added this portion of code to handle it :

```
const unhandledRejections = new Map();
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
    unhandledRejections.set(p, reason);
});
process.on('rejectionHandled', (p) => {
    unhandledRejections.delete(p);
});
```

Hope this will help ...

Comment: One more observation is - I'm running the app from laptop for testing and when it is disconnected from network, it loses connection to DB and it may have caused this resource error. After adding the handler, it is not happening any more.